# Class and subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

Ok i have these classes here :

```
public class item {
    public String name,constructor ; 
    public int year; 
    public double price ; 
    public item(String name,int year,double price,String constructor){
        this.name = name ; 
        this.year = year ; 
        this.price = price ; 
        this.constructor = constructor ; 

    } 
    public String getName(){
        return name ; 
    } 
    public int getYear(){
        return year ; 

    } 
    public double getPrice(){
        return price ; 
    }
    public String getConstructor(){
        return constructor ; 
    } 
    public void setName(String name){
       this.name = name ; 
    }
    public void setYear(int year ){
       this.year = year ; 
    } 
    public void setPrice(double price){
       this.price = price ; 

    }
    public void setConstructor(String constructor){
       this.constructor = constructor ; 

    }
}
```

and also class hardware:

```
public class hardware extends item {


private String proccesor;
private String motherboard;
private String RamMemory;
private String drive;

public hardware(String name,  String proccesor,String motherboard, String RamMemory, 
String drive ) {
super(name);
this.proccesor= proccesor;
this.motherboard= motherboard;
this.RamMemory= RamMemory;
this.drive= drive;
}

public void setProccesor (String proccesor) {
this.proccesor= proccesor;
}

public void setMotherboard(String motherboard){
this.motherboard= motherboard;
}

public void setRam(String RamMemory){
this.RamMemory= RamMemory;
}

public void setDrive(String drive){
this.drive= drive;
}





}
```

Now when i compile item, it compiles fine and no problems pop up.But when i try to compile the hardware class, cmd gives me this message:

```
 Hardware.java.11: error: constructor item in class item cannot be applied to given types super(name);
Required :String,int,double,String
Found: String
Reason: actual and formal arguments lists differ in length
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling a constructor in the superclass that does not exist.

In your hardware constructor,

```
super(name);
```

Should be changed to call the only available constructor in item:

```
public item(String name,int year,double price,String constructor)
```

In Java, all arguments are required when calling a method. Unlike a language like Javascript, where if you don't pass something, an implicit `undefined` is passed.

Answer (score 2):

When java attempts to compile `hardware.java` it sees the statement `super(name)` and looks for a constructor in class `item` which takes a `String` as its only argument, because that is how you are calling it.

However, the class `item` only has one constructor defined, and it expects 4 arguments:

```
public item(String name,int year,double price,String constructor)
```

Because an `item` must have a year, price, and contructor specified, you may need to add those fields to the constructor for the `hardware` class, and then you could call `super(name, year, price, constructor)` from your hardware constructor method.

Alternatively, you could modify the `item` class to also provide another constructor, omitting the year, price, and constructor argument.

```
public item(String name){
        this.name = name ; 
    }
```

After that change, `super(name)` from the hardware constructor will now find the `item(String)` constructor method in class item.

Answer (score 1):

look at the `item(String name,int year,double price,String constructor)` constructor.
you should call

```
super(name,year,price,constructor)
// change the parameters as you want but the types should remain
```

or add a constructor like this to the item class:

```
item(String name) { ... }
```

---

BTW class names should (not must) start with capital letters.

Comment: i changed the command **super(name);** to : **super(String name,int year,double price,String constructor);** but now it gives me 9 errors instead of 1 it was giving me before the change.

Comment: First, you would need to either have the hardware constructor take in a year, price and constructor arg, and then change `super(String name, int year, double price, String constructor);` to `super(name, year, price, constructor);` OR you would need to create an item constructor that takes only a name and just call `super(name);`

Comment: @user3546087> Well, I don't know what's the logic of your program, so I don't know what do you mean by `hardware(...)` and `item(...)`, I just said that you should call `super` with a String, an int, a double,a String as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

`class item` doesn't have a constructor that just takes a `String` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`Item class` does not have `item(String name)` constructor.